# Mysql SELECT IN GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I want to use  IN a subquery in mysql but I need `GROUP_CONCAT` to have a `having`
(my sub query work well).

```
SELECT pd.* FROM Product pd 
WHERE perimeter_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) 
FROM Perimeter p 
GROUP BY p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id 
HAVING count(id) > 1);
```

Comment: Ok... Where is the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do a `INNER JOIN` like

```
SELECT pd.* 
FROM Product pd 
INNER JOIN Perimeter p ON pd.perimeter_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT p.id) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use GROUP_CONCAT. This query will return all (network_id, productRange_id, country_id) that have multiple IDs:

```
SELECT p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) 
FROM Perimeter p 
GROUP BY p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id 
HAVING count(id) > 1
```

This query will return all IDs in different rows:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM
  Perimeter p INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) 
    FROM Perimeter p 
    GROUP BY p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id 
    HAVING count(id) > 1
  ) d ON (p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id) = (d.network_id, d.productRange_id, d.country_id)
```

and this is your final query:

```
SELECT pd.*
FROM Product pd 
WHERE
  perimeter_id IN (
SELECT p.ID
FROM
  Perimeter p INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.id) 
    FROM Perimeter p 
    GROUP BY p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id 
    HAVING count(id) > 1
  ) d ON (p.network_id, p.productRange_id, p.country_id) =
         (d.network_id, d.productRange_id, d.country_id)
)
```